# SQL query to add spaces in between a value

Tags: sql

Can you help me with the sql update query used to add spaces in a field.

Eg. "INC MP99"
Result should be like "IN    C     MP    99"

There are 4 spaces in between IN & C and MP & 99 , Between C and MP it has to be 5 spaces.

Thanks

Comment: What logic do you need to follow to determine where to insert a space?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [tour] and also read [ask] to get better answers for your questions.

Comment: question not cleared. by the way, you can use the update query.

Comment: Are you using some programming language to interface with MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract parts of the data using `SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )` or equivalent and then put it back together.

```
DECLARE @data nvarchar(50) = 'INC MP99'
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@data,0,1),'    ', SUBSTRING(@data,2,5), '     ', SUBSTRING(@data,6,50) )
```

This will work with MS SQL Server. If you are looking for other database syntax, then you will have to adjust.